# Previously working selenium script suddenly fails to establish a new connection

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have been working with my python Selenium script for a while now, but suddenly I have started getting this error:

> urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost',
> port=56467): Max retries exceeded with url:
> /session/c159fe7f3ae326faada8651af9241ac9/url (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x7f5e45e868f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]
> Connection refused'))

I have checked my webdriver, which seems to be correctly initialized, and the URL is also correct, but for some reason, I get the said error. This is my main script:

```
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--auto-show-cursor')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)

    driver.get(url)
    print("checking error")
    print(driver)
    print("URL")
    print(driver.current_url)
    errors = []
    source = driver.page_source # The error is thrown in this line
```

Comment: If code used to work before, and now after an update it stopped working, you can try `pip install -U selenium==4.10.0` thus reverting to a previous Selenium working install, and see if it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Also, add the below line of code in the arguments stack. It will help you to establish the connection between Selenium API and with latest browser version.

```
 options.add_argument("--remote-allow-origins=*")
```